# "TypeError: $ is not a function" when trying to use cheerio like jquery

Tags: javascript, bots, cheerio

I am trying to make a bot to check if an item is in stock. I based it off of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57TEZq8O360, but changed the url. Although I can console.log the content of the webpage when I try to use cheerio like jquery I get this error "TypeError: $ is not a function". I know cheerio is installed and works as I have declared it with "const $ = require('cheerio');" and have been able to use it elsewhere in my file. Is there a typo that I am missing? My broken code is below.

```
async function checkStock(page){
await page.reload();
let content = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
console.log(content);
$("link[itemprop='availability']", content).each(function(){ //error here
    let instock= $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase().includes("outofstock");
     if(instock){
        console.log("no"); 
  }
});}
```

Comment: Could you share the snippet where you are loading the html into cheerio. Something like - `const $ = cheerio.load('<ul id="fruits">...</ul>');`

Answer (score 0):

[You need to load the HTML into cheerio, and *then* cheerio will give you the `$` API:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

```
const $ = require("cheerio");

// ...

async function checkStock(page){
    await page.reload();
    const content = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
    const $ = cheerio.load(content);

    $("link[itemprop='availability']", content).each(function(){ //error here
        let instock = $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase().includes("outofstock");
        if (instock) {
            console.log("no"); 
        }
    });
}
```